# Making a 200 V pulse supply

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, pulse

I'm looking to build a power supply that can continuously create pulses of at least 200 V (no more than 300 V). These 200 V pulses must have a pulse width of 0.4 uS. Each pulse should have a rise rate of 1.5 kV/uS, with the rise rate referring to the part of the leading edge of the pulse between 25% and 75% of the pulse amplitude.

As this is a trigger for the thyratron, the rep rate is not terribly important, although having at least 5 Hz would be preferable.

Any advice for how I could get started down this road would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The supply must have an impedance between 50-100 ohms

EDIT2: It's okay if the rise rate is a bit faster (i.e. 2 kV/uS), most Mosfets are much faster than 1.5. It's simply that this is being used for an old thyratron.

EDIT3: The 0.4 uS is also the minimum pulse width, it's okay to go a bit over.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks, I'll get that fixed in a second

Comment: must say pF of load

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 The load is a thyratron, unfortunately I can't tell you very much about its capacitance.

Comment: This may not be that easy.. If you have smallish hydrogen thyratron (say 20kV/500A) the gate drive circuit will 'see' 20kV for about 50-100ns after triggering. So the second pulse might be an issue.

Comment: I would suggest a mosfet as a switch and a step up transformer.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The supply only needs to put out 200 V, not 20 kV. Could I use something a bit smaller than a thyratron?

Comment: My point is that the anode voltage finds its way to the thyratron grid for a brief time.

Comment: @user69795 If I were to use a mosfet, how should I wire it to create the desired pulses?